# java: Simple timer use

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask, seconds

I am a beginner to coding and I have been struggling to get the java timer to re execute this current time code every second. I tried thread.sleep and couldn't get it to work. I got this code setup from a tutorial on Youtube but it gives me the following error. Thanks.

```
Error: Main method not found in class timedate, please define the main        method as:
  public static void main(String[] args)
```

Below is the code.

```
   import java.util.*;

class timedate extends TimerTask{
   public void run() {

    long s = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l;

    final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";
    final String ANSI_HOME = "\u001b[H";
    System.out.print(ANSI_CLS + ANSI_HOME);
    System.out.flush();

    double t = s%(60*60*24);
    double b = t%(60*60);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println((int)(t/(60*60))%(12)+":"+(int)(b/(60))+":"+(int)(b%(60)));
    System.out.println("");

    }
 }

class mainclass{
   public static void main (String[] args) {
     Timer time = new Timer();
     time.schedule(new timedate(),1000,1000);

     }

  }
```

Comment: You are trying to execute wrong class. Use proper command to execute.

Comment: you use eclipse IDE or command line to execute your program ?

Comment: I use command line. Thanks for your help now its working.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks that your Main Method is located in your timedate class when it's in fact in your mainclass class. That is probably due to the fact that you have two separate classes in one file, which is illegal in java. You can however nest the timedate class inside your mainclass class or create a separate file for your timedate class and import that file into the file that contains mainclass. Also rename the main file to mainclass.java. I hope this helps.